# Alterar o URL da Página, ao clicar em links dentro de um iframe

Tags: iframe

Tenho um sistema de postagem em um site feito no muse.
Gostaria que quando eu clicasse em leia mais, o site gerasse uma url com o iframe com a postagem.

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> function resizeIframe(obj){ obj.style.height = 0; obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px'; } </script> <iframe target="_parent" src="filhosdegaia.atwebpages.com/postagens.php"; onload='resizeIframe(this)' scrolling="no" style="width:100%;border:none;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Por motivos de segurança, tudo que é feito fora do iframe não reflete para dentro dele e o mesmo ocorre de dentro para fora.